# Parsing String Array into Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, string, rest, arraylist

I'm calling a RESTful Api from my Java application which provides me result in following format:

```
["Item1", "Item2" , "Item3"]
```

How do I parse it into ArrayList object?

Code:

```
    private String getResponseString(URI URL) {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
    get.setURI(URL);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get, context);
        return getASCIIContentFromEntity(response.getEntity());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(Static.DebugTag, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Static.DebugTag, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}

private String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity)
        throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    InputStream in = entity.getContent();
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    int n = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        n = in.read(b);
        if (n > 0)
            out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Now I want to make another function that takes the String returning form getASCIIContentFromEntity() as param and return an Arraylist.

P.S. I have response in a string object.

P.P.S. Title may be misleading as in I don't have idea what to call it.

Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: It'd amazing to know why I got a neg vote? I'd try to avoid that in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the string appears to contain valid [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), you could use a JSON parser, such as [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), to parse the string. See [Arrays Examples](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples) and [Collections Examples](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples) in the manual.

Comment: @Umayr: I've added links to the manual; there are some examples there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a loot at java.util.Arrays.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]);
```

Comment: Would it work for "["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]" too? as I have all results in a String Object. I added my code, that might help to elaborate my objective.

Comment: Nope, but you could make a single String into a String[]. Take a look at .split() method in the String class. I believe that without any arguments passed in the method will spit a string based on the 'space' character so each item would be their own index in the array.  Since the string is formated in JSON syntax, you could try using regex, StringTokenizer, or search around for a apache-commons or guava for a utility that could handle the split for you or cop-out and try looking at the JSON class to see if can cleanly parse out the text.